# Can I buff an Arcane Eye?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

I want to make my [Arcane Eye](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/arcane-eye) invisible and give it darkvision. Is that possible? E.g. the text of [Clairaudience-Clairvoyance](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/clairaudience-clairvoyance) says:

> Unlike other scrying spells, this spell does not allow magically or
>   supernaturally enhanced senses to work through it.

So I would say, YES. But I am not sure about it, since I cannot find a Scrying Spell Tag in the Arcane Eye description.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the rules for [Arcane Eye](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/arcane-eye), emphasis mine:

> You create **an invisible magical sensor** that sends you visual
>   information. You can create the arcane eye at any point you can see,
>   but it can then travel outside your line of sight without hindrance.
>   An arcane eye travels at 30 feet per round (300 feet per minute) if
>   viewing an area ahead as a human would (primarily looking at the
>   floor) or 10 feet per round (100 feet per minute) if examining the
>   ceiling and walls as well as the floor ahead. **It sees exactly as you
>   would see if you were there.**

To me, this states that the eye lets your character see as with darkvision etc., as long as your character has these modes of vision.

As @Randomorph notes, the Arcane Eye is already invisible, so it does not require any spells to make it invisible.

Comment: You may want to emphasize the fact the Arcane Eye is *already* invisible as well, as the Asker has stated they want to *make* the Eye invisible.

Answer (score 2):

## The spell [*arcane*](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/arcaneEye.html) [eye](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/arcane-eye) lists its school as *[divination](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Divination) (scrying)*

Spells of the [divination](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Divination) subschool scrying—like the spell [*arcane eye*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/a/arcane-eye)—, unless otherwise stated, create magical sensors that have in common the following features:

> [A] scrying spell creates an invisible magical sensor that sends you information. **Unless noted otherwise, the sensor has the same powers of sensory acuity that you possess. This level of acuity includes any spells or effects that target you, but not spells or effects that emanate from you.** The sensor, however, is treated as a separate, independent sensory organ of yours, and thus functions normally even if you have been blinded or deafened, or otherwise suffered sensory impairment.

(Emphasis mine.) Thus a caster that possesses [darkvision](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/special-abilities#TOC-Darkvision)—whether, for example, naturally because the caster's a typical [orc](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/featured-races/arg-orc) or magically because the caster's affected by a spell like [*darkvision*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/darkvision) or wearing a magic item like the [*goggles of night*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/e-g/goggles-of-night)—creates a scrying sensor that likewise possesses darkvision. The same goes for a caster that, for example, possesses [low-light vision](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Low-Light-Vision-Ex-) or is benefiting from an effect like the spell [*true seeing*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/true-seeing). However, an effect that, instead, [emanates](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Aiming-a-Spell) from the caster—like, for example, the effects of the spell [*deathwatch*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/deathwatch)—aren't shared with the scrying sensor.

Magical sensors that function differently will say so. For example, the spell [*clairaudience/clairvoyance*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/clairaudience-clairvoyance) says, "Unlike other scrying spells, this spell does not allow magically or supernaturally enhanced senses to work through it."

Further, as the previous quotation mentions, unless otherwise stated, magical sensors created by spells of the subschool scrying are normally [invisible](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Invisible). However, the sensors can still be detected:

> A creature can notice the sensor by making a Perception check with a DC 20 + the spell level. The sensor can be dispelled as if it were an active spell.

(In *Pathfinder*'s antecedent *D&D 3.5* only a creature with at least an Intelligence score of 12 could make a far more difficult [Intelligence ability check (DC 20)](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/magicSchools.html#scrying) to detect a scrying sensor—a good change by *Pathfinder* in this player's opinion.) Typically, this limitation on scrying sensors is impossible to eliminate and only mitigated by, for example, employing the feat [Heighten Spell](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/heighten-spell-metamagic---final), which will, in addition to other effects, increase the Perception skill check's DC.

Further, not only because the sensor's normally invisible but also because it's neither creature nor object, creatures struggle even to *target* the sensor with many effects (exceptions include, for example, [*dispel magic*](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/dispelMagic.html#dispel-magic)). For instance, because the spell only targets creatures, a scrying sensor typically can't be targeted by an effect like the spell [*hide from undead*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/h/hide-from-undead), and because the spell targets creatures or objects, a scrying sensor typically can't be targeted by an effect like the spell [*invisibility*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/i/invisibility) (and such an effect would normally be redundant anyway).

And, finally, a scrying spell effect's creator can sense that the scrying spell effect has been blocked by lead sheeting or magical protections, such as an effect like the spell [*nondetection*](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/nondetection.html#nondetection).